# How to convert a numeric form to date form

Tags: r, date

I am trying to convert the field which is numeric in my dataset df to a date format using R.

The value is present as sear_date in the dataset and is in format "20181212".
However, I would like to convert this field from numeric to date in R

```
df$search_date=as.Date(df$search_date,origin = "1970-01-01"))
```

I expect the output to just change the type of the variable from numeric to date. However, it changes the fields themselves to wrong data

Answer (score 2):

Use `as.Date` with the indicated format.  If it is numeric convert to character first.

```
as.Date("20181212", format = "%Y%m%d")
## [1] "2018-12-12"

as.Date(as.character(20181212), format = "%Y%m%d")
## [1] "2018-12-12"
```